# how to avoid switch-case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Please, how can I refactor this code to avoid switch-cases? Do I need to use Dictionary instead? Is there a way of changing commands without adding new case and make it automatically...I mean this solution will not depend of the amount of cases. I hope my problem is clear.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleHelp ch1 = new ConsoleHelp();
        Plus pl = new Plus();
        Minus mn = new Minus();
        Divide dv = new Divide();
        Multiply mlt = new Multiply();
        Sinus sin = new Sinus();
        Tangent tan = new Tangent();
        Square sq = new Square();
        Degree dg = new Degree();
        Percent pr = new Percent();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("command> ");
            string com = Console.ReadLine();
            if (com != null)
            {
                switch (com.ToLower())
                {
                    case "?":
                        ch1.Helpper();
                        break;
                    case "plus":
                        pl.Sum();
                        break;
                    case "minus":
                        mn.Minusvalue();
                        break;
                    case "divide":
                        dv.Dividevalue();
                        break;
                    case "multiply":
                        mlt.Multvalue();
                        break;
                    case "sinus":
                        sin.Sinusvalue();
                        break;
                    case "tangent":
                        tan.Tangentvalue();
                        break;
                    case "square":
                        sq.Squarevalue();
                        break;
                    case "degree":
                        dg.Degvalue();
                        break;
                    case "percent":
                        pr.Pervalue();
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("The command is not supported. Enter one of the valid commands.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you have a different class for each operation? That doesn’t seem very useful.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the switch case? What, in particular, is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: This seems like a rather appropriate use of a `switch` statement.  I fail to see how you could dynamically handle this.  How are you going to know, at runtime, which class file to use?  It seems the operations are statically defined at compile time.

Comment: Could potentially use `Dictionary<String, Action>`. Since none of the functions requires parameters, could wrap them all in an action block.

Comment: Point of interest, I believe when you have "sinus" you mean to use "sine".

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` but it wouldn't really help to make your code more maintainable. You'll still have something like your switch where you statically add the key value pairs.

Comment: Only idea I have to refactor is to move the declarations for `Consolehelp`, `plus`, `minus`, etc inside their respective switch statements.

Comment: Good question, wrong place, voted to move it to [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Could do one of these:

```
Dictionary<String, Action> myActions = new Dictionary<String, Action>() {
    {"One", delegate { ActionA(); }},
    {"Two", delegate { ActionB(); }},
    {"Three", delegate { ActionC(); }},
    {"Four", delegate { ActionD(); }}

};

myActions["StringInput"]();
```

When you define the dictionary, make sure that you have access to the outside classes so that they can be closed over.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the question is "how to find many named handlers for action".

Some possible options:

- dictionary of command name to handler (delegate or interface)
- mark handlers with custom attributes (either method or whole class, depending on your need) and use reflection to find them all. I.e. `[CustomCommand(Name="percent")]`
- use dependency injection container that have named instances (like Unity) to add many implementation of the "command handler" interface.
- simply use "command handler" interface as marker and find all classes implementing it via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is nothing wrong with using a `switch` in your example, you could use a `Dictionary<string, action>` to map your commands to appropriate actions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleHelp ch1 = new ConsoleHelp();
    Plus pl = new Plus();
    Minus mn = new Minus();
    Divide dv = new Divide();
    Multiply mlt = new Multiply();
    Sinus sin = new Sinus();
    Tangent tan = new Tangent();
    Square sq = new Square();
    Degree dg = new Degree();
    Percent pr = new Percent();

    var commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            { "?", ch1.Helper },
            { "plus", p1.Sum },
            { "minus", mn.MinusValue },
            { "divide", dv.DivideValue },
            { "multiply", mlt.Multvalue },
            { "sinus", sin.Sinusvalue }, 
            { "tangent", tan.Tangentvalue }, 
            { "square", sq.Squarevalue }, 
            { "degree", dg.Degvalue }, 
            { "percent", pr.Pervalue}, 
            { "c", () => Environment.Exit(0) }
        };

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("command> ");
        string com = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(com))
        {
            Action action;
            if(commands.TryGetValue(com))
                action();
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The command is not supported. Enter one of the valid commands.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary can help you

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

dic.Add("divide", () => dv.Dividevalue());

var com = "div";

dic[com]();
```

Naturally you must check that the command was registered, maybe with

```
Action action = null;

if (dic.TryGetValue(com, ou action))
{
    action();
}
```